# 32bit Ruby compile fails on Lion

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-lion, 32-bit

I am trying to install a 32bit build of Ruby on Lion so that I can do some work with Oracle.  However I can't get it to build.

With 1.9.3-p0 this is as far as I get:

```
linking miniruby
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1: i386: No such file or directory
make: *** [miniruby] Error 1
```

My build variables are as follows:

```
CC = /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
LD = ld
LDSHARED = /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -dynamic -bundle
CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=write-strings -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=shorten-64-to-32 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -arch i386 -pipe
XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I. -I.ext/include/i386-darwin11.2.0 -I./include -I.
DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  -arch i386
SOLIBS =
```

I am using the following configure:

```
./configure --with-arch=i386 --prefix=/Users/fenris/.rbenv/versions/32-bit
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using rvm myself but tried out on rbenv as well and worked for me:

## RBENV compiling 32 bit ruby-1.9.3-p0

!!! installing **libyaml** before doing this could be needed

**Installing libyaml**

```
wget http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz
tar -xzf yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz
cd yaml-0.1.4
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/ruby-1.9.3-p0_32bit
make 
make install
```

**installing ruby**

```
cd
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p0.tar.gz
tar -xzf ruby-1.9.3-p0.tar.gz
cd ruby-1.9.3-p0
autoconf
./configure --disable-pthread --with-opt-dir=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/ruby-1.9.3-p0_32bit --with-arch=i386 --prefix=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/ruby-1.9.3-p0_32bit 
make
make install
```

## RVM compiling 32 bit ruby-1.9.3-p0

```
export rvm_archflags='-arch i386'
export rvm_architectures='i386'
export rvm_configure_flags=--target=i686-apple-darwin11
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p0 --32 --patch osx-arch-fix -n i386
```

...

**Verify that you are running a 32 bit ruby**

```
$ irb
['foo'].pack('p').size

// should return 8 on 64bit and 4 on 32bit.
```

Comment: make sure to tack on --with-gcc=clang if you get a warning about compiler error

Comment: I get the following error on ./configure (rbenv version). ld: in /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386) for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
     Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: How do you force libyaml to build as 32-bit? I tried `ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386"` but it still built as 64-bit. And the ruby make can't build psych because of this (says libyaml is missing).

Comment: Found the answer to the yaml problem. You have to set these env vars when configuring libyaml: `CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-arch=i386" CFLAGS="-arch i386" LDFLAGS="-arch i386"`

Comment: @brad did you ever figure out how to get around the libsqlite.dylib issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you're using rvm:

```
rvm_architectures="i386" CFLAGS=" -arch i386" LDFLAGS=" -arch i386" rvm install 1.9.3-p0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rvm install 1.9.3-p0 --with-gcc=clang
```